# AVCaptureSessionにAVCaptureMetadataOutputのインスタンスを追加するとEXC_BAD_ACCESSエラー

Tags: swift

SwiftでQRコードリーダーの開発を行っています
[このサイト](https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/3-avfoundation/008-qrcoderida)を参考にしながら作成しているのですが、
`AVCaptureMetadataOutput()`のインスタンスをセッションに追加しようとすると、RUNはできるのですが、起動後に以下のように`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`が出でしまいます
`addOutput`関数の引数には`AVCaptureOutput`のオプショナル型のプロパティを指定するようなので
特に間違ったところはないように見えるのですが、考えられる原因がわかりません。
どなたかアドバイス頂けないでしょうか。

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var myVideoInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    var myMetadataOutput:AVCaptureMetadataOutput!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mySession: AVCaptureSession! = AVCaptureSession()

        var myDevice: AVCaptureDevice!

        myDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)

        do {
            myVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:myDevice)
        } catch  {
        }

        if mySession.canAddInput(myVideoInput) {
            mySession.addInput(myVideoInput)
        }

        myMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        if mySession.canAddOutput(myMetadataOutput) {
            mySession.addOutput(myMetadataOutput)
            myMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            myMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
        }
    }
}
```

[image: RUNを押した後]

Comment: あなたのコードは(参考にされた元サイトのコードも)いろいろなエラーを無視していますので、異常があった時に全く情報が取れない作りになっています。とりあえず`catch  {}`の部分を`catch { print(error) }`とかに置き換えてみてください。それと確認ですが、テストは実機で行っていますか?シミュレーターにはカメラ機能はありませんから、カメラ機能を使ったほとんどのコードはcrashします。

Comment: いろいろ試してたら解決しました！お騒がせしました(ｰ ｰ;)

Comment: 解決に至る経過がシェアするに足るご経験だと思われる場合は、是非ご自分で回答を投稿してみてください。再現性の少なそうな些細なミスだった場合は…、クローズ要求でもするのが妥当なんですかね？私の経験上では取るに足りないとご本人が思っている些細なミスでも、意外と全く同じミスにはまる人は多いものです。